# How to split MoviesLens dataset for cross validation?

Tags: python-2.7, recommendation-engine

Grouplens website no longer provides the *pre-splitted dataset*, is there any python script or other language to split the `movie-lens1M` dataset?

Anyone could provide a demo?

Answer (score 0):

Use shuf ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/shuf)) to randomly shuffle the lines. Then use split ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split)) to separate into pieces.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Leb: They're *CLI utilities*. Those are the *online mirrored copies of their man pages*. This is not a link-only answer.